# Board game errors unexpected identifier?

Tags: java

So basically I keep getting errors within a few lines of code, yes I'm missing an if clause on line 31 I've tried both with and without it and it still doesn't work, can someone give me a hand on figuring out what I've managed to mess up on?

MAIN CLASS:

```
package simpleboardgame;

public class RealTile {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   Tile newTile = new Tile();
 }

}
```

PACKAGE:

```
package simpleboardgame;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Tile extends JFrame{

  int rowMax = 10;
  int columnMax = 10;
  int row;
  int col;
  int n = 0;

 public Tile ()
 {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(rowMax, columnMax));
  frame.setSize(600,600);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  JLabel nextLabel = new JLabel();

  int[] activeCell = new int[100];

  for (int row = 0; row < rowMax; row++)
  {
   for (int col = 0; col < columnMax; col++);
   {

    {
     nextLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(//Color.BLUE ));
     nextLabel.setBackground(http://Color.black );
     nextLabel.setOpaque(true);

    }

  else 

    {
    nextLabel = new JLabel();
    }

   frame.getContentPane().add(nextLabel);

   }
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Unexpected Identifier on Line 1, then it highlights some of the { in red, however when I change that it stays the same.

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: I removed them at first and I literally can't see anything wrong with any of it.

Comment: I could sense an extra "}" in your tile class.

Comment: So what exactly do I need to change?

Comment: Try deleting one of the "}" in the end from the Tile class.